# How to get Entity Reference Autocomplete results to display in a table?

Tags: views, entities, blocks

I am currently working on a site which will take in an unlimited amount of nodes (in this case inventory numbers) for a Sales Order which I can then save, view and export into a CSV in Drupal 7. I am wondering how I can take the results of the Sales Order and form the results into a Views Block that is attached to the Sales Order NID page.

For example here is my Entity Reference Autocomplete: [image]

Then when I save this, I want to be able to view the results in a table when I click on the Sales Order. I would like the table to display certain information from the item (which I know is done in a view).

Here is how my Views Block is set up currently (with the preview results): [image]
[image]
I am unsure as to why nothing shows up on either the preview or the page. 
[image]

I have also tried using Inline Entity Reference but that doesn't seem to work either. I am a Drupal Ameteur, but need some help with this.

Is the Entity Reference Autocomplete list not saving properly or does it save it anywhere at all? If so, how do I access it?

EDIT: So I have the block assigned to the Sales Order Content type and it is assigned in the Content section in the Blocks menu. (I think this is right)
 [image]
I also just changed the Pages section to No Restriction and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing thats jumps out at me is that you have "Referencing Entity" rather than "Referenced Entity" in your views relationship.

Because you are showing  a view of content with the field, you are already showing the referencing entity. What you want is a relationship to the **referenced** entities.

Have you also got the views block to display on the correct content type?

You have the correct contextual filter set up (you can use "get content id from url" rather than raw value).

Make sure the block is shown in a region on all of the referencing entities content type.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by correct content type. Is there a menu where I'm supposed to put it?

Comment: You have created a view to show the reference field as a list of referenced entities. If you are using a contextual ID of the node, you now need to display the block created by the view, on that node. Go to structure>blocks and enable the block the view created